# PHP: Use str_split to push to an existing array

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of strings. I want to loop through that array and place every 3 characters into another array, eg:

```
array('abcdefg', 'hij', 'klm');
```

becomes:

```
array('abc', 'def', 'hij', 'klm');
```

I have created the below:

```
  $masterArr = array();

  foreach($arr as $i){
    array_push($masterArr, (str_split($i,3)));  
  }
```

But the `str_split` in this creates sub-arrays within $masterArray.

Is there a way I can simply use `str_split` to push directly to $masterArray?

Comment: What happened to "`g`"? Is everything with length < 3 discarded?

Comment: @insertusernamehere ideally, but I can deal with it later in masterArr

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve it by using array_merge() fucntion

```
$masterArr = array();
foreach($arr as $i){
   $masterArr= array_merge($masterArr, str_split($i,3));    

   // OR if you need only elements which have exact 3 characters then use below line
   // $masterArr= array_merge($masterArr, array_filter(str_split($i,3), function($k) {return strlen($k)==3;}));    
}
```

Comment: `array_filter()` requires the array to be the first argument, not the closure.